# Java conversion of % sign failing

Tags: java, string, exception, format

I am trying to do  string.format of a string and to produce a literal % I am using 2 signs. But still java is failing to recognize it and I have no idea why. It tries to use the following characters as a conversion and it fails.

And here the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'tX'
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkDateTime(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
at files.CreateFilters.main(CreateFilters.java:218)
```

I've tried to use the unicode but the same exception is thrown. Please advise.

Comment: How about you produce a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem? (The string in question shouldn't need to be even *slightly* that long...)

Comment: why don't you use StringBuilder?

Comment: Where's the code with `String.format`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Braj, I ended up doing that and it worked out fine. Please reply with that so that I can solve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using StringBuilder prooved to be a better solution for a bigger string.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, the correct escape is double `\\` (not double percent, however in your use case you may actually need to double that to `\\\\`) like so -

```
final static String segmentClassLines = 
  "package com.nedstat.reporting.filters.cmf.%s.visitor%s;\n" + 
  "\n" + 
  "import com.nedstat.datamodel.db.sitestat.enums.ItemType;\n" + 
  "import com.nedstat.parameters.StringParameter;\n" + 
  "import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.ParameterTypeAlias;\n" + 
  "import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.VisitSelector;\n" + 
  "import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.annotation.FilterInfo;\n" + 
  "import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.annotation.Group;\n" + 
  "import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.annotation.Option;\n" + 
  "import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.annotation.Parameter;\n" + 
  "\n" + 
  "/**\n" + 
  " * generated by automated tool\n" + 
  " */\n" + 
  "\n" + 
  "@FilterInfo(id = %s, type = ItemType.STANDARD, name = \"%s\", groups = {\n" + 
  "    @Group(name = \"%s\", template = \"%s\", parameters = {\n" + 
  "        @Parameter(type = ParameterTypeAlias.ENUM, options = {\n" + 
  "            @Option(value = \"VisitSelector.FIRST\", description = \"\\%TXT_SEGMENTATION_FILTER_OPTION_FIRST\"),\n" + 
  "            @Option(value = \"VisitSelector.LAST\", description = \"TXT_SEGMENTATION_FILTER_OPTION_LAST\"),\n" + 
  "            @Option(value = \"VisitSelector.ANY\", description = \"TXT_SEGMENTATION_FILTER_OPTION_ANY\"),\n" + 
  "            @Option(value = \"VisitSelector.EVERY\", description = \"TXT_SEGMENTATION_FILTER_OPTION_EVERY\") }),\n" + 
  "         @Parameter(type = ParameterTypeAlias.WILD_CARD) }) })\n" + 
  "public class %s extends com.nedstat.reporting.filters.cmf.AbstractRibVisitorFilter\n" + 
  "{\n" + 
  "  public %s(VisitSelector visitSelector, StringParameter labelValue)\n" + 
  "  {\n" + 
  "    super(visitSelector, %s.class, labelValue);\n" + 
  "  }\n" + 
  "}\n";
```

When I print that String I get

```
package com.nedstat.reporting.filters.cmf.%s.visitor%s;

import com.nedstat.datamodel.db.sitestat.enums.ItemType;
import com.nedstat.parameters.StringParameter;
import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.ParameterTypeAlias;
import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.VisitSelector;
import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.annotation.FilterInfo;
import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.annotation.Group;
import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.annotation.Option;
import com.nedstat.reporting.filters.annotation.Parameter;

/**
 * generated by automated tool
 */

@FilterInfo(id = %s, type = ItemType.STANDARD, name = "%s", groups = {
    @Group(name = "%s", template = "%s", parameters = {
        @Parameter(type = ParameterTypeAlias.ENUM, options = {
            @Option(value = "VisitSelector.FIRST", description = "\%TXT_SEGMENTATION_FILTER_OPTION_FIRST"),
        @Option(value = "VisitSelector.LAST", description = "TXT_SEGMENTATION_FILTER_OPTION_LAST"),
        @Option(value = "VisitSelector.ANY", description = "TXT_SEGMENTATION_FILTER_OPTION_ANY"),
        @Option(value = "VisitSelector.EVERY", description = "TXT_SEGMENTATION_FILTER_OPTION_EVERY") }),
     @Parameter(type = ParameterTypeAlias.WILD_CARD) }) })
public class %s extends com.nedstat.reporting.filters.cmf.AbstractRibVisitorFilter
{
  public %s(VisitSelector visitSelector, StringParameter labelValue)
  {
    super(visitSelector, %s.class, labelValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: @nuno_cruz Also, there is a `%%` on line 19 in resulting text right before `TXT_SEGMENTATION_FILTER_OPTION_FIRST`. Did you mean to write `%s`?

Comment: @jzelenkov You should reread the first sentence of the question.

Comment: ...oh yes, thanks. I misunderstood @nuno_cruz's question. So OP actually wants to have a `%` sign right at that place?! That confuses me. What could be a use case for that? As I understand `%s` is to be replaced later, but `%` alone? Any ideas?

Comment: @jzelenkov I think it's supposed to indicate the column is a percentage. Like 15%, 25%. So a literal % sign.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch is right I want a literal % sign to appear. But that didn't work for me either.